# Как читать данные курсора внутри другого курсора?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

Надо завершить разработку, сделанную сотрудником, который покинул компанию. Пытаюсь понять курсор, встроенный внутри другого курсора. Что-то вроде этого:

```
CURSOR c_fund as select col_1, col_2, 
    CURSOR (select col_10 * {some formula} clo_n, col_m 
            from table2 
            where col_8 is not null)
[...]
```

Как можно тогда прочитать в коде внутренний курсор?

Когда выполняю запрос главного курсора, получается такой результат:

```
COL_1        COL_2   CURSOR
-------      ------  -------
11619187    604441  (CURSOR)
11619187    604434  (CURSOR)
11619187    604439  (CURSOR)
```

После двойного клика в TOAD на `CURSOR`, появляется новое окно:

```
CLO_N   COL_M
-----   ---------------
009511  1g0-M-TPT_BNM
009511  1g0-Q--213_BNM
009511  C--F_R*P_C:R:CT
[...]
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to read a cursor inside another cursor in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52631519) от участника [@Mohamad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6899593/mohamad)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52631519

Answer (score 2):

Переменные курсора помогут. Воспроизводимый пример кода ниже доллжен помочь понять, как это работает.
Возмите сразу на заметку:

- Выражение `CURSOR` возвращает указатель на открытый курсор, работа с которым не отличается от с обьявленным в блоке явным курсором.
- Запрос в выражении `CURSOR`, который не вернёт ни одной записи НЕ вызовет исключения `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

```
declare
    type refcursor is ref cursor;
    CURSOR maincur IS
        SELECT l.city, CURSOR (
            SELECT d.department_name||'/'||e.last_name
            FROM hr.employees e 
            JOIN  hr.departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id) emps
        FROM hr.locations l
        WHERE l.location_id = 1700;
   innercur refcursor;
   city hr.locations.city%type;
   title varchar2 (64);
begin
   open maincur;
   loop fetch maincur into city, innercur;
       exit when maincur%NOTFOUND;
        --Теперь, можно циклом выбирать записи внутреннего курсора
        loop fetch innercur into title;
            exit when innercur%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line (city||': '||title);
        end loop;
        close innercur;   
   end loop;
   close maincur;
end;
/
```

Выведет:

```
Seattle: Administration/Whalen
Seattle: Marketing/Fay
Seattle: Marketing/Hartstein
Seattle: Purchasing/Tobias
[...]
```

PS Использована стандартная схема HR, которaя [доступна на GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633084/6571020) от участника [@Steven Feuerstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4403757/steven-feuerstein)</sub>